# angular-google-map.js throwing RangeError on route

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I am using angular-google-maps to embed Google Maps into my Angular application.

Everything is working fine and I can see the map and all the markers I have defined in one controller. However, when I route to the other page (that does not use a map) with a different controller, I am getting the following error.

> RangeError: Invalid array length
>     at Object.angular.module.service.decrement (angular-google-maps.js:1180)
>     at angular-google-maps.js:6084
>     at l.$get.l.$broadcast (angular.js:14720)
>     at l.$get.l.$destroy (angular.js:14340)
>     at z (angular-route.js:907)
>     at angular-route.js:940
>     at angular.js:6956
>     at $get.h (angular.js:7096)
>     at l (angular.js:7756)
>     at x (angular-route.js:933)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, I've updated angular-google-map to 2.1.0 and it works.

they're already fixed it.